# PRINT Statement in MSSql

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

Simple I need to print 4 varchar variables

```
 @divisionId,@Divisionname,@isActive,@Divcode
```

above are variables.

```
 PRINT  @divisionId,@Divisionname,@isActive,@Divcode
```

ERROR

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

showing error . please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually find it easiest to output multiple values in a single `print` statement using *concat* as it automagically casts types to string:

```
print concat('p1=', @p1, ', p2=', @p2...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use four separate statements:

```
 PRINT  @divisionId
 PRINT  @Divisionname
 PRINT  @isActive
 PRINT  @Divcode
```

Or you can use string concatenation as below:

```
PRINT  cast(@divisionId as varchar)+','+ @Divisionname +','+ cast(@isActive as varchar)+','+@Divcode
```

I assumed that @divisionId and @isActive is not of varchar type. So I have converted those into varchar.

Answer (score 0):

PRINT is an alternative of RAISERROR function.
Both are meant to send strings to console output.

This means a single number is implicitly converted to nvarchar. And this causes the error when trying to send multiple numbers. As this is clearly not a single string.
CONCAT helps because again it uses implicit Casts to accomplish the conversion.

For debugging I use

```
DECLARE @mystring  nvarchar(2000)
;
SET @mystring = ...string conversion and concatenation work here...
;
RAISERROR( @mystring, 0, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT
;
```

Unlike PRINT which outputs after the whole statement ends this way drops console output during the execution.
Excellent to figure out where in a long procedure(s) execution the execution stands and for evaluating some critical transformations while those happen.

Comment: And just to make sure: I use this during debugging procedures.

Comment: If you are going to use `RAISERROR` you might as well use the string interpolation feature and not bother with `@mystring` - i.e.  if  all  4 variables are varchar as stated. `RAISERROR( '%s %s %s %s', 0, 1, @divisionId,@Divisionname,@isActive,@Divcode ) WITH NOWAIT`